How could an AI opponent force humans to waste time?
The AI war happened, and the AI won.  On Mars, there's a few hundred human survivors.  The AI doesn't really want to kill them - why didn't matter.  But it doesn't want them to be an active threat, such as getting access to fusion weapons, so it forces activity on them to burn their potential.
But it does this by appearing to be stupid, acting in irrational but predictable ways.  The humans believe that they're operating "smart", exploit loopholes.
Example: Any human of the surface carrying a radio jammer is ignored.... if it's powerful enough, which effectively means they have to carry ~20kg of gear.  Not crippling, but enough to slow down any surface work.
The humans say "Look, we can operate freely on the surface!"
The AI ignores the jamming in favour of laser communication links and lets the humans get on with their mandatory weight lifting.
But that's one thing.  What else could the AI enforce on the humans, which would limit human operational effectiveness while allowing the humans to "win"?

A few hundred people are not enough to develop nuclear weapons or delivery systems - it would take a civilisation of millions at the least.  More importantly, a few hundred people are probably not enough to maintain a working habitat and survive on Mars, without massive stockpiles of spare parts, medicine, food etc that it would be difficult to justify the existence of.  So, what specifically is the AI's objective re the survivors, since "doing nothing" is sufficient for the humans to die on their own without being a threat?

A) Fusion weapons are around. Just not geographically close to the humans.  Fission would be doable as well, with much less effort.  B) The AI is deliberately keeping them just alive.  Essential resources always seem to be just inside raiding range.   The AI can be tricked deliveries if the humans "hack" hard enough.... ok, when the AI can tell they are desperate enough.  AI wants to keep them around, because replacing them if they die out will be near impossible.  And one thing it doesn't like is losing options.

I can think of a lot of things, too many, this is idea shopping not a question.

Questions about the actions of characters are not allowed. Questions which can be answered with several equally valid opinions are not allowed.

The other thing is we're missing a huge amount of data here. What are the AI's material capabilities?

The AI has functional 2050 level tech industrial base.  Drones on Mars, satellite surveillance, perfect infiltration of human IT systems.  This is no longer a conflict - we lost.

This is sounding very "Dr Evil"ish.  Even with nuclear devices all over the place, assuming the AI wasn't stupid enough to leave a population of missile experts alive and/or a group within walking distance of its mainframe, all it needs to do is deny them a delivery system that will let them target its key physical locations.  Much simpler than trying to convince them that an AI that could defeat all other humans everywhere is trivially fooled, not to mention unnecessary since they will really be scrambling to stay alive.

@user2702772 Given the gap between our technology in 2000 and what we're using today "2050 level tech industrial base" (or any other 25ish year period you care to name since the industrial revolution) is a meaningless statement as far as understanding it's actual, total, and particularly space industry, material capabilities.

Just get the humans a really good game, and watch as they sink in waaaaay to much time.

@Ash not sure I agree.  Back in 2000 we could see the way things were going. Think cars and car production.  Increased automation, massive increase in electronic complexity with multiple ECUs. Nothing unexpected.  Genetic engineering - we've not even progressed as far as we thought we might.  I can't think of a single thing that wasn't obvious back then, apart from maybe domestic 3D printers.  Internet on phone via WAP was even a thing. Edit: But functionally the AI could build anything it wants, up to and including a horde of remote controlled cyber dogs.

You should read The Defenders - a short story by Philip K. Dick (available on Project Gutenberg). It is similar to what you are asking. Also, for what it's worth, the short story is the basis of the later book The Penultimate Truth by Dick.

Consider Facebook - already an infinite time sink.

@JonCuster How do you think the AI won in the first place :D

From the [help/on-topic], When asking questions keep in mind that the goal of the site is to help you build your world, not to tell your story.

They don't need to.
300 people isn't enough to maintain a tech base of any size. Just limit reproduction above a set number and keep building up your tech level. With the full resources of a solar system you'll advance technologically much faster than 300 humans.
Give them dumb drones to fight.
Make it like a game. Fly dumb drones around the surface searching for humans to kill, which are loud, have poor visibility, and which guard supply depots. If the humans want to survive they need to outhack the drones and steal the supplies. Help the humans have a more martial culture based off warrior skills than a scientific culture, with just enough tech skills to maintain their tech level, and let them play endless games of outwitting their robotic overlord.

"Hide from the surveillance drone that flys over every hour!".... Ignores the geosynchronous satellite perfectly over their heads... I like.  You might be right about needing to give them either more people, more automated production or more free resources.

Yeah, you could have all sorts of fitness games from the drones. Hide from the surveillance drone, freeze in front of the motion tracker, run from the gorilla apes. Lots of fun. And yes, 300 is about enough to maintain a village on earth. With mars, you'd need more.
